# Python 3.2 remove issue

Tags: 12.04, python

I have install python3.2 alongside python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 through `sudo apt-get install python3.2`.

And now I removed it through `sudo apt-get remove python3.2`. Then when I type `python3.2` in terminal, it show:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 20:10:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting all installations of python via Synaptic, then install Python 2.7.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program `/usr/bin/python3.2` is not in the package `python3.2` but in `python3.2-minimal`. As `python3.2` depends on that it has been installed automatically.

To remove all of Python 3.2 you need to remove `python3.2-minimal`.